# Do any Stack Exchange sites deal with time-management questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Are there any sites on the Stack Exchange Network where questions about time management are considered relevant? (I'm referring to time management in the general sense of the term: keeping track of deadlines, staying focused on work, etc.)

There is a Stack Exchange site (in beta) called [Project Management](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/), but most of the questions on that site appear to be about software project management. Are questions about non-software-related project management considered relevant on this site, or should they be posted elsewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personal time management would be on topic on [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com).

[Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com) *does* accept and encourage questions about non-software project management, but they are generally expected to be in a professional context.

Comment: Personal Productivity seems not to exist now. Was it superceded by something?

Comment: @TravisWell Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the most relevant site: it's called [productivity.stackexchange.com](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/).